# how to find minimum score of a 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, 2d, min

How to find minimum score of a `2d array`.

---

My array is like :

```
[['john', 20], ['jack', 10], ['tom', 15]]
```

I want find the minimum score of student and `print` his name.
tell me how to write that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only one student:

```
student_details = [['john', 20], ['jack', 10], ['tom', 15]]
student_detail_with_min_score = min(student_details, key=lambda detail: detail[1])
print(student_detail_with_min_score)
print(student_detail_with_min_score[0])
print(student_detail_with_min_score[1])
```

Output:

```
['jack', 10]
jack
10
```

`min` function finds the minimum of `student_details`, but it will use `student_details[i][1]` as the key while comparing.

Read the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) to understand how the `min` function works with the `key` argument.

---

If you want to get all the students with the minimum score:

```
student_details = [['rock', 10], ['john', 20], ['jack', 10], ['tom', 15]]

min_score = min(student_details, key=lambda detail: detail[1])[1]

student_details_with_min_score = [
    student_detail for student_detail in student_details if student_detail[1] == min_score
]

print(student_details_with_min_score)
```

Output:

```
[['rock', 10], ['jack', 10]]
```

Comment: Please explain how the code works. Simply posting code that the OP (possibly) does not understand, is not that helpful, it just promotes copying & pasting

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check!